# Why is mysql_fetch_object failing when class_name is null even though that's the default?

Tags: php, mysql, object

I'm trying to write a simple database wrapper class.  I've written a method like so:

```
public function get_objects($sql, $class_name = null) {
    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $this->connection );
    $objs = array();
    if( $result ) {
        while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, $class_name)) {
            $objs[] = $obj;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    return $objs;
}
```

If I don't specify $class_name when calling this method the call to mysql_fetch_object fails with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class '' not found in ...
```

The problem is I don't want it to use a class_name.  I just want it to perform the default behavior as if I hadn't specified a class_name.

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default *isn't* null. The default is [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) (from the docs):

> The name of the class to instantiate, set the properties of and return. If not specified, a **stdClass** object is returned.

If you want to keep the same default, you'll need to have this as your method signature:

```
 public function get_objects($sql, $class_name = "stdClass") {
     // continue as normal.
```

Comment: i think the classname should be quoted.

Comment: What will happen if he sends in a falsy second parameter?

Comment: What happens if he sends `mysql_fetch_object($result, "invalid string")`? It fails and outputs an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify a specific class, then why are you even using the class_name argument?

If you absolutely must use it, this should work

```
if ( $result ) {
   $class_name = $class_name ? $class_name : 'stdClass';
   ...
```

Comment: Because he wants "passthru" form his custom function so he needs to have a default...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it is expecting a string and you give it null. I would do an if check to see if $class_name!=null.

```
public function get_objects($sql, $class_name = null) {
    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $this->connection );
    $objs = array();
    if( $result ) {
        if ($class_name){
            while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, $class_name)) {
                $objs[] = $obj;
            }
        }else{
            while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                $objs[] = $obj;
            }
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    return $objs;
}
```